# Is there a Gmail filter for creating Chrome bookmarks using URL links in an email message?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, chrome-bookmarks

When I am surfing the web (either from my iPhone or laptop), I would like to send links of the webpages I want to read later as emails to my Gmail account. Is it possible to use filters (or any scripts) to parse for URL links in the email and drop it into a specific Chrome bookmark folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Chrome on all those devices (it's available on iOS now), the simplest option would probably be using Chrome's built-in bookmark synching feature. Just make sure you're logged in the same Google Account on those Chrome instances and you'll see bookmarks and web opene tabs from other devices.

If that cant work for you and you can do a bit of code, it's something that can easily be scripted through Context.IO.